# win32 C++ printing PRINTDLGEX not declared?

Tags: c++, winapi, printing

I am trying to figure out how to print in C++. I want to get the device context using the PrintDlgEx function, which needs a PRINTDLGEX structure. However, I cannot create a PRINTDLGEX because it says it's undeclared. I have included the Commdlg.h and Windows.h and linked the Comdlg32.lib, but all to no avail. Is there something I'm missing? I can go into the Commdlg header file and see that PRINTDLGEX is declared, but for some reason I can't use it? My operating system is Window Vista.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably undeclared because it's within a `#ifdef STDMETHOD` block starting on line #878 of Commdlg.h

[`STDMETHOD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693342(VS.85).aspx) is defined in `basetyps.h`

This post, [Customizing PrintDlgEx and IPrintDialogCallback](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30397445/customizing-printdlgex-an.aspx), might be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your target Windows version to be modern enough to support the structure, the defaults assume something ancient. Typically this will be done in your `stdafx.h` file. These definitions must come before the include of the Windows header files.

```
#define WINVER 0x0500
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#define _WIN32_IE 0x0501
```